# How to use "htaccess" on synology system for website access control?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, synology

I am trying to set up the access control for my personal website on synology NAS. Right now I am using DS212J. I found the following article teaching how to use "htaccess" on apache to achieve that.

http://www.synology.com/support/faq_show.php?lang=enu&q_id=347

But I encountered 2 problem:
1) I don't have the command "htpasswd" after ssh to my DS212J.
2) After I manually create those files, I got the username and password prompting up on the website. However, the password in "admin.pw" and "normal.pw" doesn't work when I type in. I am not sure whether it is because I didn't use command "htpasswd".

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The htpasswd executable is at /usr/syno/apache/bin/htpasswd. As that directory is not on the PATH, you have to explicitly use the whole path to use it:

Apache doesn't keep passwords in plain text, it uses a hash of them so that even if someone gets access to the password file they won't be able to log in. That's why you must use htpasswd to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, I couldn't get that synology support tutorial to work either. I am running DSM 5.1-5022 Update 4 on my own domain with ssl. Here's how it got it working:

1. Follow the steps in the following wiki: [Synology Wiki](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Apache_web_page_access_controls)
2. In the control panel, go to "Web Services" and disable SPDY for secure connections. (Gleaned from [this article](http://www.timokosig.de/blog/2014/03/fix-ldap-authentication-under-apache-on-synologys-dsm-5-0/).)

Good luck.

Comment: The Wiki you linked is now a broken link